# XUL button width attributes ignored

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a XUL button that I want to be 16x16, and I've done everything in my power to make it so:

```
<button image="chrome://npuff/content/images/gear_16.png"
        width="16" maxwidth="16" height="16"
        maxheight="16" style="width: 16px;"/>
```

The background image is 16x16.  The button ends up being somewhere in the neighborhood of 16 pixels high, but is much wider than 16 pixels.  If I set the width attributes to sufficiently high values, the button expands, but it never gets smaller than about 35-40 pixels.  Is there some undocumented minimum width for XUL buttons that Firefox is enforcing?  If some surrounding items are skewing its size somehow, how can I tell them to lay off my button?  I'm able to put an <image> in the same space with the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard buttons (e.g. in alerts and dialogs) are expected to have a minimum width. This width is applied by the theme.

Comment: What about buttons that aren't in alerts or dialogs?  The button in question is on the add-ons bar.

Comment: @cbmanica You're supposed to use a `<toolbarbutton>` in that case.